# Error undefined reference to library

Tags: c, codeblocks

I tried make simple library with one function, so I read how to make it but it doesn't work and I cannot find explanation to such an easy library. How should i write it?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main()
{
  hello();
  return 0;
}
```

hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void hello(void)
{
  printf("Hello user 4");
}
```

hello.h

```
void hello(void);
```

Comment: What is your development environment?

Comment: Did you tell the linker that there is more than one file to link?

Comment: Is this `c++` or `c`? I mean its tagged as `c++` but the code is `c`.

Comment: "It doesn't work"?

Comment: Common convention is to use C++ extensions for C++ files, such as cpp, cc, cxx and C (on case sensitive filesystems).  For header files, usually hpp, hxx, or H.

Comment: i use code blocks, yea its C sorry for wrong title/tag; the error is undefined reference to `hello

Comment: You have to link the files together depending on your environment

Comment: `hello.c` is a source file; `hello.h` is a header file; you have to compile the source to produce an object file (`hello.o`) and then either link the object file with `main.o` to create the executable (`cc -o hello main.o hello.o`), or add the object file to a library and link the main program with that library (e.g. `ar rc libhello.a hello.o; cc -o hello main.o -L. -lhello`).  The details depend on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

All of your `c` source code files should compile together as parts of one project. When you created 'hello.c' (presumably by choosing File → New → Empty File) CodeBlocks should have prompted to add the file to the active project, to which you should click the "Yes" button to confirm. Then the "Save File" dialog box should appear, and save the file as usual, edit and add the code, and compiling the project as usual should work.

However, you've already created the `hello.c` file, so you just need to tell CodeBlocks to add the existing `hello.c` file to the project:

> Right-click the project name → Add files → select `hello.c` and click OK

Recompile the project and the compiler should link the associated `.c` source files.

Alternatively, you could add `#include "hello.c"` to the list of headers in `main.c` and achieve the same result. However this is discouraged as we should leave the linking process to the compiler.